# Trigger navigation, only after user is found

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I use QuerySnapshot to go threw my documents and look for user, than I compare the user stored in the documents with the current user. I do it for navigation in the app.

```
if (user != null) {
     _firestore.collection('Devices').get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
       querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {                                
         if (doc["user"] == _auth.currentUser.email) {                             
            Navigator.pop(context);                          
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, DashboardScreen.id, arguments: doc.id);                       
         }else{                             
            Navigator.pop(context);                               
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, ScannePunktWidget.id);                             
         }                                
       });                                    
      });                                       
     }
```

The problem is, I have 2 documents, so the `querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {` goes threw all of them and triggers evertime the if statement and if the right user wasnt in the first document, else will get triggered, what I dont want.

How I can modify this code to wait for the right user and only then trigger the navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually really dangerous, as it reads all documents to find a specific one document. That may work if you have a few documents, but imagine what happens if you have thousands of devices, and each of them does a query like this.

For cases like this, you'll want to use a query to only retrieve the document(s) that matches you condition. That also nicely matches your other problem: if the query has any results, the condition is met.

So that'd be something like:

```
_firestore.collection('Devices').where("user", isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser.email).get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
  if (querySnapshot.size > 0)
     Navigator.pop(context);                          
     Navigator.pushNamed(context, DashboardScreen.id, arguments: query.docs[0].id);                       
  }else{                             
     Navigator.pop(context);                               
     Navigator.pushNamed(context, ScannePunktWidget.id);                             
  }                                
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. That looks good and I was also trying with 'where', but I didnt manage to get the id of the document where the user was found. I need it, because I pass it with arguments. `arguments: doc.id`

Comment: I added an example of that, although there may be some syntax errors in there. If you have problems getting values such as this, I highly recommend keeping the reference documentation handy: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html

Comment: This works with `querySnapshot.docs[0].id` thanks a lot. One more question: how do I know that docs has to be [0]? I know docs expect list, but why is it 0, why not 1 or any other number. So the question is: what does this number stand for?

Comment: While a query can have multiple results, your original code navigates based on the first document whose `user` value matches. This code does the same by using `docs[0]` (the first result document).